# Difference between azure integration runtime & self hosted integration runtime in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to know real life examples/use cases for Azure Data Factory(ADF) with below configurations:

- Azure Integration Runtime(AIR) default
- Self Hosted Integration Runtime(SHIR)

Additional questions:

1. Are there any additional costs associated with either of these configurations(AIR & SHIR)?
2. If I need to connect to a private network/on-prem system from ADF, would SHIR be suffice and serve the need?
3. By having AIR as additional configuration, does it bother? If it is not needed, just don’t configure AIR?

Please share your thoughts/suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One usually leverages an SHIR whenever there is need to access a source or sink hosted within a vnet like On Prem databases, SFTP, IaaS databases etc else you leverage AIR.

Now to answer ot your queries:

1. SHIR charges are less than AIR since you are paying separately for your engine by setting up your own server whereas in case of AIR, MSFT provides the engine directly thereby having more charge as compared to SHIR
   Note: this is in accordance to ADF costing and not overall costing
2. yes, to access anything hosted within a Vnet, you would need SHIR and it would suffice
3. AIR is a default configuration unlike SHIR wherein you have to set up server and install gateway. there is no action needed by individual for AIR